# How to avoid None printed when exporting jupyter notebook to html using nbconvert

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm using the following command to export a notebook to html:

```
jupyter nbconvert --no-input --to --template full html notebook.ipynb
```

However, I always get this annoying *None* print whenever I use the `--template full` option.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way I can get rid of this annoying print and still use the `--template full` option?

Comment: Are you doing this command inside a notebook? Have you tried with a semicolon as the last character of your command?

Comment: No. I'm running the command in an external terminal. I'll try the semicolon.

Comment: I'm sorry. I get it now. The 'None' is showing up at the top of the HTML it produces? Semi-colon won't help if that's the case. Can you open the produced HTML file in a text editor and share the top of the HTML file code, specifically where the `None` is and a few lines below (and above if there's any). I suspect there's something that is allowed in the full template like a logo or branding or header that isn't set to anything by default. I'm hoping the code gives you an idea where to look. Or at the very least we can make a work-around maybe that then removes this any time you want to use it.

Comment: Well I'm going with the workaround for now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Having the same problem. Is there any good solution?

Comment: "None<!DOCTYPE html>", not sure if it is the same for OP

Comment: Couldn't find anything better than the workaround